# Number of states constrained by sum

Tags: combinatorics, constraints

Assume $n$ players have between $0$ and $k-1$ chips each. The total number of states for the game is then $N = k^n$, since there are $k$ options per player.

Now assume the number of chips is constant and predefined, say $s$, and players can only exchange chips between themselves. The number of possible states should drop drastically, reaching $N=1$ in the special cases where $s=0$ or $s=(k-1)n$.

What then is the general formula for the number of states given $k, n$ and $s$? is it still exponential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for the coefficient of $x^s$ in the polynomial
$$(1+x+\dots x^{k-1})^n =\Bigl(\frac{1-x^k }{1-x}\Bigr)^n=
\Bigl(\sum_{j=0}^n {n \choose j} (-x^k)^{j}\Bigr)\cdot \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty {\ell+n-1 \choose n-1} x^\ell \,,$$
which is the convolution of the coefficients of the two power series in the product, evaluated at $s$:

$$\sum_{j \ge 0}  {n \choose j} (-1)^{j} {s-kj+n-1 \choose n-1} \,.$$

Comment: Wow. This will take me some to think over. Isn't it strange that this is not monotonic for $k$? Odd values will give an alternating (smaller) sum.

Comment: Indeed, there was a typo, $(-1)^{kj}$ should be just $(-1)^j$. This is corrected now. In your example, we obtain $7-6=1$.